# HTTPS REQUEST RETURNS ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

NodeJs backend is stored on elastic beanstalk and also added certificate approved by DNS, named on domain name: *.dateweek.de, dateweek.de
Angular frontend is stored on aws s3 connected to cloud front where is also created certificate approved by DNS.
Cloud front is connected on route 53 by a record. Domain is bought on Godaddy, where I added ns from route 53. However when I try to access my app in browser I got error: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Answer (score 0):

The common name on an SSL certificate is your domain name, which should match with the web address in your host. For example, if you want to secure yoursite.com, with an SSL certificate, your common name should be yoursite.com.

A common name mismatch error occurs when the domain the SSL certificate is installed on is not listed on the certificate (either as the common name, subject alternative name, or covered by a wildcard). It’s essentially like your site is wearing the wrong hat.

In addition to these potential causes of ”NET:ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID” errors, there are other reasons this message can pop up, such as a misconfigured redirect.

Comment: I pointed certificate to dateweek.de(my domain) and validate certificate with DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You probably resolved this, but I was having the same issue, here is a solution that I found for anyone else who runs into this issue.

[Tutorial: Front & Back-end web app deployment using AWS S3 and Elastic Beanstalk with SSL/HTTPS](https://sam-adda.medium.com/tutorial-front-back-end-web-app-deployment-using-aws-s3-and-elastic-beanstalk-with-ssl-https-dbb9fcec3b6f)